# Vue не выводит циклически изображения

Tags: vue.js

Всем привет! Целый день потратил на попытки циклически выводить изображения, которые находятся в папке. Для вывода изображений просто вывожу с бэка пути к изображениям в папке, но столкнулся с парадоксом, который никак не могу решить ибо не понимаю, почему происходит то, что происходит.

```
<div id="app">
        <div>
           <img v-for="item in aItems" :src="item">
        </div>
    </div>


// ТАК НЕ ВЫВОДИТ!!!
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    aItems: []
  },
  methods: {
    // Выводит список товаров в галерею.
    displayImagesFromFolder: () => {
      let sUrl = "https://bakeritadogs.xyz/api/data/product/display-products";
      let resArr = [];

      axios.post(sUrl)
        .then(res => {  
          this.items = res.data; 

          items.forEach(el => {
            resArr.push(el);
          });           

          this.aItems = resArr;

          console.log("items", items, "resArr", resArr, "aItems", aItems);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log("err", err);
        });
    },
```

Если я ставлю в data вручную вбиваю массив, то изображения выводятся. Если оставлю в data aItems: [] и заполню его в результате запроса с бэка, то они не выводятся. 
Не понимаю почему.

```
    // ТАК ВЫВОДИТ!!!
    var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    aItems: ["images/gallery-1.png", "images/gallery-2.png", "images/gallery-3.png"]
  },
  methods: {
    // Выводит список товаров в галерею.
    displayImagesFromFolder: () => {
      let sUrl = "https://bakeritadogs.xyz/api/data/product/display-products";
      let resArr = [];

      axios.post(sUrl)
        .then(res => {  
          this.items = res.data; 

          items.forEach(el => {
            resArr.push(el);
          });           

          this.aItems = resArr;

          console.log("items", items, "resArr", resArr, "aItems", aItems);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log("err", err);
        });
    },
```

Хотя при заполнении массива с бэка он точь такой же как и при хардкоде значений в него.
[image: При заполнении массива с бэка]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поздравляю, вы потеряли контекст.
`displayImagesFromFolder: () => {` используя стрелочкую функцию вы потеряли `this` который раньше ссылался на ваше приложение. Теперь он стал глобальным обьектом. Как результат вы создаете глобальную переменную `items`. Она будет видна из любой части скрипта.

Вам всего то надо поменять стрелочную функцию на обычную.

```js
var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        aItems: []
      },
      mounted: function() {
        this.displayImagesFromFolder()
      },
      methods: {
        // Выводит список товаров в галерею.
        displayImagesFromFolder: function() {
          let sUrl = "https://google.com";
          let resArr = [];
          Promise.resolve(["https://picsum.photos/200"])
            .then(res => {
              res.forEach(el => this.aItems.push(el));
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log("err", err);
            });
        },
      }
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <img v-for="(item, index) in aItems" :src="item" :key="index">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы, спасибо, что напомнили про стрелочные функции. Совсем забыл что они теряют его..

Comment: Да, всегда пожалуйста. Если все понятно, то примите ответ галочкой

Answer (score 1):

Я просто оставлю это тут, вдруг кому пригодится. В соответствии с советом Дениса, отрефакторил код таким образом. Теперь все выводится отлично.

```
 "use strict";

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created: function () {
    this.loadProducts();
  },
  data: {
    products: []
  },
  methods: {
    loadProducts: function () {
      let sUrl = "https://bakeritadogs.xyz/api/data/product/display-products";

      axios.post(sUrl)
        .then(res => {
          this.products = res.data;

          console.log("products", this.products);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log("error displaying products", err);
        });
    }
  }
});
```